# Insert at the beginning of a linked list?

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm having a little trouble trying to add some elements to a linked list. My problem is that despite the fact that the code adds the "proces" INSIDE the function, once I get out of it, the "Stiva" becomes empty and if I try to "print" its elements all I get is NULL. This is what I've writted so far, I'd greatly appreciate it if someone could help, I really don't understand where it fails to pass the argument through the pointer:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
{
   int prioritate;
   int id;
} TProces;

typedef struct celst
{
   struct celst *urm;
   void *info;
} TCelSt, *TStiva, **TStive;

int Push(TStiva Stiva, int id, int prt)
{
   TStiva StivaNoua;
   TProces proces;
   StivaNoua = (TCelSt*)malloc(sizeof(TCelSt));
   StivaNoua->info = (TProces*)malloc(sizeof(TProces));
   proces.id = id;
   proces.prioritate = prt;
   memcpy(StivaNoua->info, &proces, sizeof(TProces));
   StivaNoua->urm = Stiva;
   Stiva = StivaNoua;
   return 1;
}

int ShowStiva(TStiva Stiva)
{
   TCelSt *aux;
   if(Stiva == NULL) printf("CRY \n");
   for(aux = Stiva; aux!=NULL; aux=aux->urm)
   {
      printf("[%d %d]\n", ((TProces*)(aux->info))->id, ((TProces*)(aux->info))->prioritate );
   }
   return 1;
}

int main()
{
   TStiva Stiva;
   Stiva = NULL;
   Push(Stiva, 5, 8);
   Push(Stiva, 8, 1);
   ShowStiva(Stiva);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: A side issue: you declared `void* info;` in `celst`, which should be `TProces* info;`. And then `memcpy(StivaNoua->info, &proces, sizeof(TProces));` can be `*(StivaNoua->info) = proces;`. But it would be even simpler to nest `celst` as a `struct` instead of allocating memory since it contains only two `int` fields.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a pointer to a `TStiva` like this:

```
int Push(TStiva *Stiva, int id, int prt)
{
    TStiva StivaNoua;
    TProces proces;
    StivaNoua = (TCelSt*)malloc(sizeof(TCelSt));
    StivaNoua->info = (TProces*)malloc(sizeof(TProces));
    proces.id = id;
    proces.prioritate = prt;
    memcpy(StivaNoua->info, &proces,
    sizeof(TProces));
    StivaNoua->urm = *Stiva;
    *Stiva = StivaNoua;
    return 1;
}
```

Because you're modifying it in the function, and in `main`:

```
Push(&Stiva, 8, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are modifying the input argument `Stiva` in `Push` but it is only a local modification. It doesn't change the value of the variable in `main`.

My suggestion:

1. Change the return type of `Push` to `TStiva` and return the appropriate value.
2. Change `main` to use the value returned by `Push`.

```
TStiva Push(TStiva Stiva, int id, int prt)
{
   TStiva StivaNoua;
   TProces proces;
   StivaNoua = (TCelSt*)malloc(sizeof(TCelSt));
   StivaNoua->info = (TProces*)malloc(sizeof(TProces));
   proces.id = id;
   proces.prioritate = prt;
   memcpy(StivaNoua->info, &proces, sizeof(TProces));
   StivaNoua->urm = Stiva;
   Stiva = StivaNoua;
   return Stiva;
}


int main()
{
   TStiva Stiva = Push(NULL, 5, 8);
   Stiva = Push(Stiva, 8, 1);
   ShowStiva(Stiva);
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your implementation of your LL but this might help you:

[image: headInserting in a LL]